# Where is my "raw data & HTML form" option in django rest api?

Tags: django, forms, django-rest-framework

Hellow developers,

I started using django rest framework, but I am not able to see **raw data/ HTML form** options in my post request user interface. My dhango and rest framework versions are latest.

The whole API works fine when I insert the data as json inside the content textarea, but I would like to have another options as well.

[image: no options/raw and html form django rest framework]

Comment: I don't think django rest api has this options and if you are going to use token authentication this will probably not work on production, try to use postman, it's very good

Comment: I am still in early stage of learning, but I checked many questions, and tutorials, they have these options available

Answer (score 2):

*Found the answer*

using decorators (**@api_view**) will not generate those ui options,

but using inheritated classes like (**APIview**) will give you those options.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the solution. Very simple step to add in your view class, just initiate serilaizer_class at very first in class:

```
from .serializer import ReactSerializer

class ReactView(APIView):
    serializer_class = ReactSerializer # Add serilizer class here like it.

#then you can add your methods:
    def get(request):
        # write your get method
    def post(request):
        # process your post method

#field showing in api page issue cleared. thanks.
```